# rtorrent compilation error : error: #include expects "FILENAME" or <FILENAME>

Tags: compiler-errors, torrent

I'm trying to install rtorrent from sources but I'm getting an error while compiling. I'm working on a fresh Ubuntu 20.04 VM.

### libtorrent installation

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade -y
sudo apt install build-essential zip net-tools zlib1g-dev libssl-dev pkg-config libncurses-dev libncursesw5-dev libcppunit-dev autoconf automake libtool libcurl4-openssl-dev -y
cd /tmp
wget http://rtorrent.net/downloads/libtorrent-0.13.8.tar.gz
tar -zxvf libtorrent-0.13.8.tar.gz
cd libtorrent-0.13.8
bash autogen.sh
./configure
make -j 6
sudo make install
```

### rtorrent installation

```
cd /tmp
git clone https://github.com/rakshasa/rtorrent.git
cd rtorrent/
./autogen.sh
./configure
make -j 6
```

But there I get an error. I couldn't find anything interesting of google.

```
/usr/local/include/torrent/poll.h:43:1: note: ‘std::function’ is defined in header ‘<functional>’; did you forget to ‘#include <functional>’?
```

```
#include expects "FILENAME" or <FILENAME>
```

You can find all the error message [here on pastebin](https://pastebin.com/3AcCBSkH)

Any idea ?
Did I forgot to install dependencies ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using wget to download the old libtorrent source, grab the latest from github:

```
git clone https://github.com/rakshasa/libtorrent.git
```

rtorrent and libtorrent versions have be kept in sync, check the README in the rtorrent source for compatible versions.